# trying to format decimal places with commas returns white screen

Tags: reactjs, decimal, currency, money-format

I am trying to simulate a decimal place with Commas to get something like this `1,234,567.90` in turn, I get a white screen.
The code I Use is looking like this

```
Balance&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font></td>
<td width="24%" align="left" rowspan="2">
    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {numberWithCommas(accDetails.bal.toFixed(2))} Currency = {accDetails.ccy}</font><p />
    <font face="Arial Black" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </font>
</td>
```

And the function I use looks like this:

```
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}
```

This returns a white screen, I don't even get to see the Error but the Error comes trying to format decimal places for Money in react JS. I need help here.

Comment: Can you try this? https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code. Restart your development server

Comment: @JoshuaFolorunsho Nah still same challenge sir

Comment: @Revan Alright. Can you create a sandbox so I can examine the code?

Comment: can you add the complete code snippet? is because that can help us to check where is the issue.